# google colab tar: Cannot read: Input/output error

Tags: tar

When I use **!tar -xvf** in Colab，there are problems:

```
tar: ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```